# RestKit not inverse mapping date

Tags: json, restkit, restkit-0.20

Restkit is mapping my date just fine to an object, but when trying to do an inverse mapping back to json i'm getting this error:

```
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
    reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (__NSDate)'
```

Obviously this is an issue with the json parser for iOS, but I figured the inverse should be handled by RestKit as well. Anyone else experience this or have a solution?

In logging restkit I get this message right before:

```
D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:920 Finished mapping operation successfully...
```

**EDIT:

Mapping example:

```
// Define media mapping
       RKObjectMapping *mediaMapping = [Media getObjectMapping];

       // Define Post mapping
       RKObjectMapping *postMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[self class]];

       [postMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
        @"post_id":    @"postID",
        @"userID":     @"userID",
        @"title":      @"title",
        @"favorite":   @"favorite",
        @"created":    @"created",
        @"modified":   @"modified"}];

       // Define relationship in the mapping between Media and Post
       [postMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"media"
                                                                                   toKeyPath:@"media"

                                                                                 withMapping:mediaMapping]];
```

Discriptor example:

```
RKObjectMapping *entityMapping = [object getObjectMapping];

RKResponseDescriptor *successDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:entityMapping
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                                                                   pathPattern:request.URL.relativePath
                                                                                       keyPath:nil
                                                                                   statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

**UPDATE2:

Right from the dictionary I break point and inspected the offending value in the destination object. 
[11]    = @"created" : 2014-04-21 11:04:43 PDT
key __NSCFConstantString *  @"created"  0x002d3818
value   __NSDate *  2014-04-21 11:04:43 PDT 0x155bab10

I can see the issue, it appears to be passing the dictionary with the NSDate to [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: options: error:] via this method, [RKSerialization dataFromObject: error;

Should RestKit not be converting the NSDate using the RKValueTransformer I have defined before passing to NSJSONSerialization?

Open issue at github can be found [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/1705).

Comment: Show your mappings and descriptors and more (trace) log output.

Comment: Sorry, was late getting to this working on something else. The rest of the trace logs was showing everything working as normal. I'll work on getting more trace info. An ugly work around was implemented to allow work to continue, so I'll just have to undo that, but from what I remember the trace really didn't show anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: Do you somehow have an `NSString` attribute which contains an `NSDate` or something? RestKit does convert, but only if the class spec says it needs to...

Comment: All properties on the inverse should be NSDate that need to be and shouldn't be converting to strings. But I may be misinterpreting what you are saying. Do you have an example?

Comment: I mean check the @property definitions of the dates (that is what RestKit uses to determine what to do). Dates should be converted to strings before the JSON serialisation happens so you need to find what is preventing that from happening...

Comment: The model property is an NSDate are you saying this needs to be converted back to a string before inverse mapping? Are you saying RestKit should be converting the Date to String, which I believe it should be as well according to the docs: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#transforming-date-and-time-representations

Comment: RestKit should be doing it. How are you creating/sending the post?

Comment: I am facing the same issue and would like to know if you got any solution.

Comment: I did a rather nasty work around. It's on my list to come back to it in the next week.

Comment: Can you post how you're making the request? As others said, RestKit should be doing this automatically if your mappings are correctly set

Comment: II'll try posting something by end of day today or tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: Ok I've looked at this, review above edited post.